# Integrating Admob to existing application

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, google-play-services

i am trying to integrate Admob to my existing Android application. I started by reading this guide:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start

But, they are saying to change Framelayout of each fragment to Relative layout. it is very tedious task for me because I have more than 100 fragments in my application.

I searched on web but no guide found for integrating in existing application. Can anyone better explain what to do?

Comment: no, no, it should not be tedious, all they are trying to say to my understanding is just having your add display at the bottom and your fragments display on top of it, with that you need a relative layout that you can assign your fragments container from top to bottom and your add fragment will be at the bottom of your fragment container with alignParentBottom='true'.. so the add has its own fragment that automatically loads the addz and you have your app fragments that deals with the content of your app and all its in the relative layout aligned relatively to each other

Comment: thanks ...just solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand. They just used RelativeLayout as the container in the example. You could just as easily use LinearLayout or FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Layout does not matter. AdMob gives you an AdView which you are free to place anywhere. The AdView displays ads.